# foreman undefined method active_record

Tags: linux, puppet, foreman

i am trying to install foreman manually on centos 6

database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: foreman
  username: foreman1
  password: foreman
  host: localhost
  socket: "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
  encoding: utf8
```

but when populating the tables, shows this error, any ideas?

```
[root@server extras]# su - foreman -s /bin/bash  -c /usr/share/foreman/extras/dbmigrate
rake aborted!
undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000000039b62b8>
```

## 1 update:

```
[root@server foreman]# gem list --local | grep active
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.8)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.8)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activerecord-mysql-adapter (0.0.1)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.8)
audited-activerecord (3.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the restuls of the `gem list --local | grep active` commmand?

If the gem is  missing then just run `bundle update` otherwise you'll need to chech your `$GEMHOME` environment varible for hte correct paths.

Comment: posted it above

Comment: i think it could be due to multiple versions of ruby installed, the server has ruby 1.8.7 from centos repo and ruby 1.9.3 from foreman repo...

Comment: @krisdigitx you are correct, foreman is not finding the corret version. try executing `su - foreman -s /bin/bash  -c ' GEMHOME=location.to.1.9.3.gems /usr/share/foreman/extras/dbmigrate'` if that works then you would need to edit the `~foreman/.gemrc` to include the correct path and the same in `~/foreman/.bashrc`